# Simplifying Big-o notation

Tags: big-o, simplify

I know we can eliminate the lower function in our Big-O notation if it is in addition.

Something like O(4^n + n^2) will be simplified to O(4^n)

However, if it is something like O(4^n * n^2) or O(n * 3^n), how do they get simplified, now that the functions are in multiplication?

Please do help me understand

Comment: This can't be simplified , because they are order of `n` and multiply to each other , and also this question has nothing to do with python!

Comment: yep thanks, i just needed a 3rd hashtag for this!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinite_asymptotics

Answer (score 1):

You don't simplify the products.

Simplification in the sums occurs because

```
f(x) + g(x) = f(x) (1 + g(x) / f(x))
```

and for large `x`, `g / f` becomes insignificant in front of `1`.

For the products `f(x).g(x)`, there is no similar rule.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand it now.

Comment: Also, could you help me with this? Is O(1^n) bigger or O(n^2) huger

Comment: @ValliPichappan= come on, 1^n=1.

Comment: Yes i did realise that. I got slightly confused because, as per the order of big-O notations, n in the exponent is higher than n^2.